# Keep google chrome element inspector DOM tree expanded on reload?

Tags: google, google-chrome

I inspect an element in google chrome and after modifying and saving my css file 
I reload the page to view the result.

Unfortunately my DOM tree is collapsed then.

Can it be achieved that it keeps expanded (and focused) at the same point?

Comment: The bug is still in the Chrome dev tools:
[http://crbug.com/635981](http://crbug.com/635981) Please vote for it to get rid of it soon.

Answer (score 2):

You may try posting your feedback for this feature.

There's a link near the bottom of the page for posting bugs/feature requests: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/

It also says to mention keyword "DevTools" in your feature request

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me. I'm guessing as of right now this is not possible. Firebug in Firefox seems to do it, though. You may want to try that.